# List account which pass a condition and group out come by month

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have this database

```
CREATE TABLE Trainee(
TraineeID smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
Full_Name nvarchar(100) not null,
Birth_Date date not null,
Gender enum('male', 'female', 'unknown') not null,
ET_IQ tinyint not null,
CHECK (0<=ET_IQ<=20),
ET_Gmath tinyint not null,
CHECK (0<=ET_Gmath<=20),
ET_English tinyint not null,
CHECK (0<=ET_English<=50),
Training_Class varchar(15) not null,
Evaluation_Notes nvarchar (200),
 );
```

I want to select Trainne which passed a condition and group those trainnees by their month of birth

```
SELECT Full_Name, 
       Birth_Date 
FROM Trainee 
WHERE ET_IQ + ET_Gmath + ET_English >= 20 
GROUP BY MONTH(Birth_Date);



('thomas', '1988-11-30', 'male', '10', '10', '40', '1') 
('Tom', '1995-07-15', 'male', '15', '8', '30', '2') 
('emma', '1990-08-20', 'female', '15', '15', '25', '3')
```

But it is not working. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results?

Comment: ('thomas', '1988-11-30', 'male', '10', '10', '40', '1')
('Tom', '1995-07-15', 'male', '15', '8', '30', '2')
('emma', '1990-08-20', 'female', '15', '15', '25', '3')
expect their ET_IQ + ET_Gmath + ET_English >= 20 and then the result will be group by month of their birth_date

Comment: _I have this database_ Thats a table, see `CREATE TABLE Trainee`

Comment: _But it is not working._ Is not a helpful description. Does it crash and give you errors? Does it give you the wrong output? (If so show us AND what you think is the right output would be as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `ORDER BY` birth month?

Try this

```sql
SELECT Full_Name, 
       Birth_Date,
       MONTHNAME(Birth_Date) 
FROM Trainee 
WHERE ET_IQ + ET_Gmath + ET_English >= 20 
ORDER BY MONTH(Birth_Date), Full_Name;
```

`ORDER BY`  is the SQLish way to control how your result set is sorted. `GROUP BY` allows you to summarize your data, doing things like this:

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(Birth_Date),
       COUNT(*) How_Many_Birthdays 
FROM Trainee 
WHERE ET_IQ + ET_Gmath + ET_English >= 20 
GROUP BY MONTH(Birth_Date)
```